# How To Convert Server-Client Chat To Client-Client Chat [Python Socket Programming]

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I have a python code which allows the user to connect to a server and send messages to it and get same thing in reply.
I want to **modify** this program so that I can chat from one client pc to another client pc through one main pc server.

It would be great if you could explain how it works too.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import socket
import thread
import sys
def chat(conn):
    while 1:

       data=conn.recv(1024)
       reply=data
       if not data:
           break
       print "Sending" + reply
       conn.sendall(reply)
try:
    socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error,msg:
    print "Failed To Create The Socket"
    sys.exit()
print "Socket Created"  

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9201
try:
   socket1.bind((host,port))
except:
   print "Unable To Bind"
   sys.exit()
print "Bind Completed Sucessfully"
socket1.listen(10)
print "Socket Is Listening"
while (1):


   conn,addr = socket1.accept()
   print "Connected With "+addr[0]+" On Address "+str(addr[1])
   thread.start_new_thread(chat,(conn,))
```